# JQuery Not able to bind blur event to all <input> elements in a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, iframe, jquery-plugins

I am trying to bind blur event to all "input" elements in the page. It has multiple input elements, there are some input elements even inside the "iframe".

I am able to bind blur events which are outside the iframe but not inside.

Here is some code I tried:

```
$('body iframe').contents().find('body').delegate('input','blur',function(e){
   alert('blur');
});

$('body,iframe').children().find('input').on('blur',function(e){
   alert('blur');
});
```

The HTML-structure

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id = abc> <!--start of abc div -->
            <form>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <input name="hello"/>  <!--  able to bind event to this input -->
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form> 
        </div> // end of abc div

        <div id="pqr"> // start of pqr div
            <iframe name="e1menuAppIframe">  <!-- iframe element (Does have more properties) -->
                <html>
                    <body>
                        <div id="abc">
                            <form>
                                 <table>
                                     <tr>
                                         <input name="hello"/>      <!--not able to bind event to this input -->
                                     </tr>
                                 </table>
                             </form>
                         <!-- more forms -->
                    </body>
                </html>
            </iframe>
        </div>    <!-- end of pqr div -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Both are not working for elements inside the iframe.

Is there a general solution to bind to all input elements inside the page in spite of iframes.

Also there are some requests that load dynamic iframe elements into the page, on and delegate functions are not binding blur events to newly added iframes.

Comment: If you Inspect Element on browser you will see another html and body tag inside frame. So I think this is the problem!

Comment: Does the contents of the Iframe come from another domain? In other words, is your Iframe opening an external URL?

Comment: No the contents are from the same domain only . When i open the iframe in firebug, it is like a new page DOM starting from <html> <body>..........

Comment: Can you show us the code here. I want to see the markup of the Iframe as well. Maybe you are missing something there.

Comment: Please find the updated HTML code structure.

Comment: um just concern if u binding event in the page on load than dynamic content(dynamic iframe ->inputs) might not attach.

Comment: We can do that with the help of .on() method . the only problem is the selector.. Need proper selectors for input elements inside iframe

Comment: Is it possible to write a selector to bind blur event to all input elements inspite of the DOM hierachy(if it inside iframe or not) ???

Comment: your example has content in the iframe `<iframe><html>`, are you setting the src on you iframe? e.g. `<iframe src="page.html"></iframe>`

Comment: No contents inside the iframe are dynamically loaded even without page refresh.

Comment: Is there a general solution to bind blur event to all input elements inside the page in spite of iframes.??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the below code working for my dynamic iframes, but this is working only for the first level of iframe . In one of my page there is an iframe inside an iframe for those input elements it is not getting binded..

```
$('body iframe').load(function(){
    $("body iframe").contents().find('input').on('blur', function() {
                onblur(this); 
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to refer to the `document` object inside of that iframe, you can't just search with jQuery in an iframe. for example

```
$("iframe").contents().find('input').on('blur', function() {
  console.log(this.name);
});
```

basically the problem is that `window` and the iframe will have separate contexts and documents, you can't simply traverse from one to another, you need pick one of them as a context first

Comment: Instead of giving the name of the iframe ie)"e1menuAppIframe"  can we write some general selector because there might be multiple iframes in a page and my objective is to bind blur event for all the input elements in a page and execute some function based on that blur

Comment: yes, you can, `$("#frame-id").contents().find("input")` should do the trick

Comment: oh, i think i see what's the problem. in your first example you `delegated` blur events, and they don't bubble, so you can't delegate them, you need to attach the event directly to an input field

Comment: Nikolay i think this will definetely work for static iframes, but i have dynamic iframes in my pages, so i think the events are not getting binded to the new elements in the page

Comment: no, you won't be able to bind events delegation to the insides of another frame, because events triggered by the iframe elements won't leave the iframe context

Comment: can you help in extending the above to second level of iframe?